# Facebook: how to share a single photo from an album without "linking" the whole album?

Tags: facebook

Each and every time you hit Share on a picture, the link Facebook creates will open not just the picture in the lightbox, but the whole album of the picture.

How to prevent that to be able to share only the picture?

Comment: You may create separate album for this particular picture.

Comment: do you also want to share the comments for the pic?

Comment: @bronislav: Yes of course, but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @AyushShanker: Comments does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the pic in either in the same tab (Inline) or in another tab...

In case you have opened it in the same tab (the pic opening in a frame above the previous page)

1. click on `Options` at bottom
2. click on `Get Link`

In case you have opened it in a new tab

1. Click on `Get Link` which you will find on right- bottom of the picture

**ALSO**: In case you don't even want the person recieving the link to read the comments, do this:

1. Open the pic in full
2. Right click on the pic and then `Copy Image URL` .

   This link should look something like `https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/263265_377992872319381_1411429080_n.jpg`
3. sharing this link would mean sharing the pic only, **and nothing else**

Answer (score 1):

I actually discovered a better way.

1. Post your photo to your regular timeline, not in the photo album.
2. Confirm that the photo appears in your timeline.
3. Open the photo and then choose 'Options' at the bottom of the photo and select the 'Move to Other Album' option.

This will put just the photo on your timeline, forcing Facebook hold its place there and then you move it to the album now that FB is committed it to your timeline. Folks can then browse your time and still the photo.

Comment: Has 'move to other album" option moved somewhere else? I can't locate it (using browser on destkop).